# Is the win7 clock calendar available as a control for applications?

Tags: .net, calendar, controls

Is the calendar used in the Win7 clock display available as a reusable control to other applications? If so, do you know of a .NET wrapper for it?

[image: Calendar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `DateTimePicker` control that is basically a calendar very similar to the one windows has but there is no .NET control for the clock.

Comment: It is a calendar alright, but it feels like it's from the 1990s (and it probably is).

Comment: If you run the application on Windows 7, you'll get Windows 7 calendar because DateTimePicker Control uses Windows APIs to draw the calendar.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `DateTimePicker`/`MonthCalendar` are the exact same control as used by this clock applet. I wouldn't have even tried it was it not for @Mohammad's comment! :)